# Time.new and Date.new .strftime("%A") returns different day for the same parameters

Tags: ruby

Solving [Unlucky Days](https://www.codewars.com/kata/unlucky-days/train/ruby), I encountered, that:

```
require 'date'
Time.new(1001,1,1).strftime("%A") # => Thursday
Date.new(1001,1,1).strftime("%A") # => Wednesday
```

Is not the same day. The correct one (iGoogled) is the `Time` one.

Why is that?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Date` by default uses the Julian calendar.  When you're dealing with dates that far in the past you're going to get weird behaviour prior to calendar reform.

```
irb(main):013:0> Time.new(1001,1,1).strftime("%A")
=> "Thursday"
irb(main):014:0> Date.new(1001,1,1, Date::GREGORIAN).strftime("%A")
=> "Thursday"
```

More detail here:
https://gist.github.com/pixeltrix/e2298822dd89d854444b